# Is there a way to remove the status effect of other players in survival mode?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

Since the debug tricks don't exist in the Bedrock Edition, I was wondering if there was any way to remove statuses like invisibility from other players.

Comment: Hi Azurasora, what have you tried so far? Have you read [this post](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13507/what-to-do-before-asking-a-minecraft-commands-question) on Arqade Meta yet?

Comment: @Joachim Ah, i haven't sorry. But I'm not asking for a command to remove status effects as those can only be done with elevated permissions.

I'm asking if there's a way to remove other player's effects, whether that be by an item or some other method.

I know that you can self-remove effects by drinking milk but I don't know if that's applicable to other players.

Comment: @Azurasora What debug tricks do you use for this in the java edition? I don't think that there are any debug tricks that can remove an effect from a player.

Comment: What is a "debug trick", that you are (presumably) claiming exists in Java Edition but not Bedrock Edition?

Answer (score -1):

Just drink milk and the effects will be removed. If you are making an adventure map and need a command, use this: 
/effect  clear

Comment: Hey, could you change your avatar to a static image instead of something animated?

Comment: Wait a second. Why?

Comment: @brododragon So there used to be a Stack Exchange policy against animated avatars, but it looks like that may have been due to a bug that has since been resolved. If it turns out that bug is still in place, and your avatar needs to be changed, we'll let you know. Sorry for the confusion!